# Absolute value function not recognized as Disciplined Convex Program (CVXPY)

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, cvxopt, cvx

I am trying to run the following optimization using CVXPY:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

weights_vec = cp.Variable(10)

er_vec = cp.Parameter(10, value=np.random.randn(10))
prev_h_vec = cp.Parameter(10, value=np.ones(10))
tcost_vec = cp.Parameter(10, value=[0.03]*10)


objective = cp.Maximize(weights_vec @ er_vec - tcost_vec @ cp.abs(weights_vec - prev_h_vec))
prob = cp.Problem(objective)
prob.solve()
```

However, I get the following error:

**cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically: 

The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not: 

param516 @ abs(var513 + -param515)**

The absolute function is convex. Hence, I am not quite sure why CVX is throwing an error for the absolute value function in the objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCP-ness depends on the *sign* of `tcost_vec`.

As this is a (unconstrained) *parameter* it's not okay.

Both of the following will work:

```
# we promise it's nonnegative
tcost_vec = cp.Parameter(10, value=[0.03]*10, nonneg=True)

# it's fixed and can by analyzed
tcost_vec = np.array([-0.03]*10)
```

Given the code as posted, there is not reason to use parameters (yet).

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I was going through the DCP rules and cannot seem to find this condition. Do you happen to know where I can find it?
https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/disc_cvx_prog.pdf

Comment: [This](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html#sign) indicates it a bit.

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah abs(x) is convex but -abs(x) is not.